# PORT=6008 env-cmd -f ./scr/Env/.env.uat react-scripts start 'PORT' is not recognized as an internal / external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs, frontend, git-bash

On cloning React frontend and running npm i, I ran into the above error. I have tried adding port to env but couldn't find a way through around it.

app-name@0.1.0 start:uat

`PORT=6008 env-cmd -f ./scr/Env/.env.uat react-scripts start

'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Frontend .env REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:4000

How can I add PORT to env using gitbash?

In package.json, I have the following:

```
"scripts":{
"start": "PORT=6008 env-cmd -f ./scr/Env/.env.development react-scripts start",

"start:uat": "PORT=6008 env-cmd -f ./scr/Env/.env.uat react-scripts start",

"start:prod": "PORT=6008 env-cmd -f ./scr/Env/.env.prod react-scripts start",

"build":...
},
```

**Note:** *I even installed react-scripts globally but couldn't resolved it.*

Comment: Does the environment variables have the exact names `.env.development`, `.env.uat` etc inside the `src/Env` directory?

Comment: To set an environment variable on Windows you need to write `SET PORT=6008`, you're omiting the set command.

Comment: Yes, it does @kanuos

Comment: @Alejandro I edit package.json scripts section to look like this ```"scripts":{
"start": "SET PORT=6008 env-cmd -f ./scr/Env/.env.development react-scripts start",

"start:uat": "SET PORT=6008 env-cmd -f ./scr/Env/.env.uat react-scripts start",

"start:prod": "SET PORT=6008 env-cmd -f ./scr/Env/.env.prod react-scripts start",

"build":...
},``` although, not showing the error again but it is not loading

Comment: @kanuos & @Alejandro, I was able to resolve the issue with the insight provided by your comments. The PORT=6008 was moved to .env's files and was removed from script section of the package file. Also, I delete node_module folder then run the commands `npm cache clean --force and npm install